# retrieving website html, but the code runs twice

Tags: php, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I have this code, and whenever it runs, it executes twice. This is a problem, because i need to display this information for a user.

I am somewhat not familiar with arrays that much, and therefore i'd like your expertise on the subject.

My code is as follows:

```
$wwwLink = "http://agynix.com/";
$IMEIapproved = false;
$data = file_get_contents($wwwLink);
//In the pattern the "class" is the div class, and the "div-res" is the value of the class
$pattern = '%<div\b[^>]*?\bclass\s*+=\s*+([\'"]?+)\bdiv-res\b(?(1)\1)[^>]*+>((?:[^<]++|<(?!/?div\b|!--)|<!--.*?-->|<div\b[^>]*+>(?2)</div\s*>)*+)</div\s*>%isx';
$matchcount = preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);
if ($matchcount > 0) {
    print_r($matches);
}
else {
    echo "Holy shit! Back to the drawing board";
}
```

My question is; how do i make this code only retrieve the information once? Is it the `echo/print_r`, is it the array information, is it the pattern, or is it my incompetence?

Comment: If the code is realy run twice this is done externally and you have to provide calling code. If you refer to the `$matchcount` being `>1` this depends on the data the website serves to you and the regular expression you use. In this case nothing is run twice.

Comment: There are no elements with a class of `div-res` on http://agynix.com/. In fact `-res` appears nowhere in the source code.

Comment: I know there isn't... Sorry, i changed the link but had forgotten to change the class value.

Comment: @urzeit if i change the >0 to >1, it will display the error message. If anyone could please provide some example code? it would be really appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps, but... Do you know that `preg_match_all` puts into `$matches[0]` strings that matched the whole expression and into `$mathches[1]` - strings that matched first parenthesized subexpression?.

Comment: Hold on.... You gave me a great idea. I'll try something and get back to you guys. :-)

Comment: As you instructed, i changed the variable to $matches[0].... And it finally worked! I HAVE to read up on arrays! :-)))

Comment: Another question you might be able to help with: If i would wanna sort the information, so for an example exclude button and stuff.... How would i go about that? Would i change the $pattern value, or would i do some other php code?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You could modify the $pattern value, you could also check each element of $matches[0] array for existence of string 'button' in it, and if it is there, delete the element.